# Calender UI AngularJS 2

Tags: calendar, angular

Does anyone know a functional calender UI to use with AngularJS 2?
I searched on Google, but couldn't quite find the type of calenders which can be used with AngularJS 1.

Comment: You can take any calendar and just wrap it into component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are schedule and calendar components in PrimeNG.

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Comment: wow, this is an awesome site, thank you!

Comment: this is not mobile friendly